# How does the sandbox in a WatchKit 2.0 extension app work?

Tags: watchkit

I'm using WatchKit 2.0 and the new `WCSession` class to message back and forth between the watch and phone applications. I need to generate a number of graphs which is handled on the phone and then image data is being returned back through a callback. I know that the WatchKit has access to `NSFileManager` I'm just not sure where to store the data.

Just to clarify: I am wondering if the directory structure for the sandbox on a WatchKit extension is the same as an iPhone application. Is using `NSDocumentDirectory` the recommended place to store images? Is these any special rules/limits/guidelines? I can't find much about this in the documentation.

Comment: Hi I'm already transferring/receiving the data, I'm wondering about the sandbox for a WatchKit extension. Updated the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using `.DocumentDirectory` on an Apple Watch app and it's working as expected. Here's the relevant code, simplified for brevity:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveFile file: WCSessionFile) {

    let documents_path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
    let path = String(documentsPath) + "/my_new_file.png"
    let dest_url = NSURL(string: "file://" + path)

    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(file.fileURL, toURL: dest_url!)
        print("New file located at: \(path)")
    }
    catch let err as NSError {
        print(err)
        return
    }

}
```

There's some relevant documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/UpdatetheAppCode.html, namely:

> Data placement. WatchKit extensions must take a more active role in managing files. The container directory for your WatchKit extension has the same basic structure as the container for your iOS app. Place user data and other critical information in the Documents directory. Place files in the Caches directory whenever possible so that they can be deleted by the system when the amount of free disk space is low.

Comment: Thanks that's the answer I was looking for! So I guess the cache directory is a better option for a resource that can be re-created.